# Style text in Numbers formula

Tags: iwork, numbers

I have a numbers formula used in invoice generation:

```
="Invoice terms: "&CONCATENATE(Terms)&", please pay by ..."
```

Which returns:

> Invoice terms: 14 days, please pay by ...

Is there a way to apply a style to only part of the formula? I want the outputted "Invoice terms" to be bolded:

> **Invoice terms:** 14 days, please pay by ...

Is this possible?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible. While you *can* format the characters in a text cell individually, the format option of a formula cell applies to the whole cell.

Answer (score 1):

Although one cannot style individual characters in a formula, one feature of Apple **Numbers** is the canvas.  One can take advantage of this by adding tables and text objects anywhere.

[image: Text object example]

The above screen shot uses a static (as the OP's "Invoice terms" text is hard coded in their formula example, it is assumed static) text field placed next to the table (a single cell table with no border, in this case) containing the cell with the formula.

The OP's use of the `CONCATENATE` function is unneeded as the ampersands do the same job.  To use `CONCATENATE` in this case:

```
=CONCATENATE(Terms,", please pay by...")
```

Where Terms is the reference to the cell containing the Terms text.

Detailed screenshot:

[image: Concatenate example]

By using a number for the days, this can be used in a calculation against the Invoice date to determine the date payment is due.  But that is a topic for another question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Formats apply to entire cells and cannot be applied to only part thereof.  Can you not put "Invoice terms:" in a different cell?